# Increase load test over time

Tags: google-app-engine, load, jmeter, load-testing, apachebench

I would like to test the load of my App Engine App.

From the [load test google recommendation](http://youtu.be/T_BQevqRp44). Query per second should increase gradually.

[image: Load test recommendation]

So I would like to add 1 connection every second to my load test.
How can I do that? I search for AB (Apache Benchmark) and JMeter without success.

Maybe my question is very basic, but as I'm not use to load testing I don't google it properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want one connection every seconds, your ramp up period (in seconds) should be equal to no. of users you choose in the thread group settings.

Refer to following tutorials to understand how to use jmeter for load testing.

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2005/jw-0711-jmeter.html

http://nico.vahlas.eu/2010/03/17/some-thoughts-on-stress-testing-web-applications-with-jmeter-part-1/

http://nico.vahlas.eu/2010/03/30/some-thoughts-on-stress-testing-web-applications-with-jmeter-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

Due to my leak of vocabulary I couldn't Google it.

It's call a "ramp-up". The word was actually in Google slide.

It can be done with JMeter under the "Thread Group" element.